# Can someone please help me explain this fallacy

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration

$$\Omega = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{1+x²}\ =\ -\int_{-1}^1\frac{dy}{1+y²} $$ $$ \text{ by using the transformation }\;  x= \frac{1}{y}$$ $$ \Omega = - \Omega ,\ 0\,\text{hence } \Omega =0 $$
but the integral is obviously $$\frac{π}{2} $$

Comment: Haven't studied integration yet but looks to me the bounds run from x = -1 to 1 which means y = 1/x will run from -1 to -infinity back around to positive infinity back to 1, which is the heart of many fallacies.

Comment: @AndrewChin This is not the problem here, you forgot to change the $\mathrm{dx}$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because frankly, it's kind of stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a slightly different take on aschepler's answer, showing a few more steps:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1{1\over1+x^2}\,dx
&=\int_{-1}^0{1\over1+x^2}\,dx+\int_0^1{1\over1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_{-1}^{-\infty}{1\over1+(1/y)^2}\,{-dy\over y^2}+\int_\infty^1{1\over1+(1/y)^2}\,{-dy\over y^2}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}{1\over y^2+1}\,dy+\int_1^\infty{1\over y^2+1}\,dy
\end{align}$$

where the negative sign from $dx=-dy/y^2$ goes into reversing the limits of integration, i.e., $\int_b^a=-\int_a^b$.

Answer (score 12):

Although $x=-1$ implies $y=-1$ and $x=1$ implies $y=1$, this does not mean the integral on $y$ can be written "from $-1$ to $1$". We need to consider the actual regions of integration, not just the boundary points.

$-1 \leq x \leq 1$ implies $y \leq -1$ or $y \geq 1$. (We can ignore the single point $x=0$.) So the correct transformation is:

$$ \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{dy}{1+y^2} + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{dy}{1+y^2} $$

The minus sign from $dy = -\frac{dx}{x^2}$ is removed, because when dealing with sets rather than just a monotone increasing or decreasing function on single intervals, we must use the absolute value of the derivative.

Comment: In some cases only the endpoints matter, but that usually requires complex analyticity. That function has two poles blocking deformation of one path (on the Riemann sphere) to another. Residues might be an unnecessarily complicated point of view to many readers, though.

Comment: Wait, this can't be right. This still gives a positive equals a negative.

Comment: I think the limits of your integrals should be from $-1$ to $-\infty$ and from $1$ to $\infty$. If you switch the order of integration, you need to add another minus sign and the RHS becomes positive too.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I don't have a very clear explanation for that which makes sense. But in the more general multi-variable transformation, we use the absolute value of the Jacobian. So for a strictly decreasing one-variable transformation we say it's $\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}$ even though $f(b)<f(a)$, but that's really just a convenience.